# breaking down for in loops for units and peers

Tags: python, list-comprehension, for-in-loop

Following understanding of list comprehensions now I’m trying to decipher units and peers from following code, if someone can please breakdown the nested structures. The intended output is clear to me but the mechanics are not. Thanks.

```
rows = "ABCDEFGHI"
cols = "123456789"

boxes = cross(rows, cols)
row_units = [cross(r, cols) for r in rows]
column_units = [cross(rows, c) for c in cols]
square_units = [cross(rs, cs) for rs in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI') for cs in ('123', '456', '789')]
unitlist = row_units + column_units + square_units

#trying to decipher following two lines
units = dict( ( s, [ u for u in unitlist if s in u ] )  for s in boxes)
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s], [])) - set([s])) for s in boxes)
```

**Edit - based on the given answer**

```
units = dict((box, [unit for unit in unitlist if box in unit]) for box in boxes)
```

is equivalent to

```
units = {}
for box in boxes:
    units[box] = []
    for unit in unitlist:
        if box in unit:
            units[box].append(unit) # where is this in above shorthand form?
```

Answer (score 0):

For units, it basically checks in which units a box `s` is contained.

```
units = dict()
for s in boxes:
   temp = []
   for unit in unitlist:
      if s in unit:
          temp.append(unit)
   units[s] = temp
```

Now for peers, it groups all the peers of a certain box `s` in a set and save it in a dictionary

```
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s], [])) - set([s])) for s in boxes)
```

You could see it this way:

```
peers = dict()
for s in boxes:
    temp = set(sum(units[s],[]))
    temp = temp - set([s])
    peers[s] = temp
```

`sum(units[s],[])` this piece of code add up all the elements in units of box `s` in a single list, then `set(...)` remove all the repetitions from the single list.

And finally `temp = temp - set([s])` remove the current box `s` from the set since a box can not be peer of itself.

Comment: thanks, while I'm looking at it, can you please also explain the `peers` related code?

Comment: you might want want to change `unit list` to `unitlist`

Comment: @Developer, you are welcome, I expect it to be clear otherwise let me know

Comment: @OmarHam I'm slowly progressing, one more thing, see my edit please regarding unit which I adopted from your answer, now my question is where is this `temp.append` (your code) or `units[box].append(unit)` (code in my edit) is in the list comprehension line? I just need some explanation to be able to start seeing it in the short syntax

Comment: `[unit for unit in unitlist if box in unit]`, this line include the for loop the if validation and the add operation, for example if you have this `[ x for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0]` you will get [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], in the case of units, unit is a list so you have a list of lists, then `(s, [u for ...]) for s in boxes` creates a list of tuples. Finally the dictionary can receive a list of tuples to create its entries, where the first element is the key and the second the value, so here `s` is the key and the list of units the value.